# flink uid. do we really need it? doesn't it use a deafult one?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

do we really use the uid method on operators?

if so..

can you suggets a more elegant way of setting it, (like extension method in c#), instead of passing 2 times the string for both name & uid?

for example instead of :

```
    streamExecutionEnvironment
    .addSource(new KafkaConsumer(kafkaConsumerOptions))
    .name("Kafka topic reader").uid("Kafka topic reader")
```

i really want something like:

```
     streamExecutionEnvironment
    .addSource(new KafkaConsumer(kafkaConsumerOptions))
    .nameUid("Kafka topic reader")
```

(where nameUid is setting both properties)

can you assist?

Answer (score 2):

The name is a value to be displayed on the Flink UI while the uid is a unique value used to maintain operator state across a possible change in the topology.  The API really does need two different setters for the two different properties as the uid should never change while the name might change as the topology evolves.